# Create an organized DF from a List of mixed type items (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list of items in a 'variable:value' format, but the same 'variable' can appear multiple times. The only thing I know is that all values that follow the 'ID' category belong to the same 'ID', so I know how many rows I need (3 in this example).

I need to create a dataframe from this list. The problem I am encountering is that I cannot add a string value to my DF ('could not convert str to float'). I am not sure how to proceed.

```
mylist = ['ID:1', 'Date: Oct 2', 'B:88', 'C:noun', 'D:44', 'ID:2', 'B:55', 'C:noun', 'D:45', 'ID:3',
          'Date:Sept 5', 'B:55', 'C:verb']

categories = []
for i in mylist:
    var = i.split(":")
    categories.append(var[0])
variables = list(set(categories))

df = np.empty((3,len(variables)))
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
counter = -1
for i in mylist:
    item = i.split(":")
    category = item[0]
    value = item[1]
    tracker = -1
    for j in variables:
        tracker = tracker + 1
        if j == category:
            float(value)
            df[counter, tracker] = value
    if category == "ID":
        counter = counter + 1
        float(value)
        df[counter, 0] = value
```

In addition, I've tried converting the items in the list to dictionary, but I am not sure if that's the best way to achieve my goal:

```
df = np.empty((3,len(variables)))
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = variables)
mydict = {}
counter = -1
for i in mylist:
    item = i.split(":")
    category = item[0]
    value = item[1]
    mydict = {category:value}
    if category == "ID":
        counter = counter + 1
        df[counter] = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict)
    else:
        df[counter] = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict)
```

Edit:

I solved it. Code below:

```
df = np.empty((0,len(variables)))
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = variables)
mydict = {}
counter = 0
for i in mylist:
    item = i.split(":")
    category = item[0]
    value = item[1]
    mynewdef = {category:value}
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter == len(mylist):
        df = df.append(mydict, ignore_index = True)
        df = df.iloc[1:]
    elif category == 'ID':
        df = df.append(mydict, ignore_index = True)
        mydict = {}
        mydict.update(mynewdef)
    else:
        mydict.update(mynewdef)
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this works

```
df = pd.DataFrame([e.split(':') for e in my_list],
    columns=['key', 'value'])
df = df.pivot(columns='key', values='value') #not tested
```